# What happens with button in a form JS DOM

Tags: javascript, forms, dom, event-listener

i'm following net ninja's tutorial on DOM and on this video about forms:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n4B7vY9SIds
He created eventlistener for submit on whole form but not the button inside the form, what happens with button in this case can someone explain to me? Someone else also asked this question in comments down bellow but no answers yet. Thanks.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
   <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet" />
     <!--<script src="app.js"></script>-->

    <title>JavaScript DOM Tutorials</title>
    </head>
   <body>
   <div id="wrapper">
    <header>
        <div id="page-banner">
            <h1 class="title">Bookorama</h1>
      <p>Books for Ninjas</p>
      <a href="http://www.thenetninja.co.uk">the net ninja</a>
      <form id="search-books">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Search books..." />
      </form>
        </div>
    </header>
    <div id="book-list">
        <h2 class="title">Books to Read</h2>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <span class="name">Name of the Wind</span>
                <span class="delete">delete</span>
            </li>
            <li>
                <span class="name">The Wise Man's Fear</span>
                <span class="delete">delete</span>
            </li>
            <li>
                <span class="name">Kafka on the Shore</span>
                <span class="delete">delete</span>
            </li>
            <li>
                <span class="name">The Master and the Margarita</span>
                <span class="delete">delete</span>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <form id="add-book">
    <input type="checkbox" id="hide" />
    <label for="hide">Hide all books</label>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Add a book..." />
        <button>Add</button>
    </form>
    <div id="tabbed-content">
    <ul class="tabs">
      <li data-target="#about" class="active">About</li>
      <li data-target="#contact">Contact</li>
    </ul>
    <div class="panel active" id="about">
      <p>Content for about tab...</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
      Vestibulum id nunc porta urna ornare rhoncus. Ut convallis ante 
    at.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="panel" id="contact">
      <p>Content for contact tab...</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
      Vestibulum id nunc porta urna ornare rhoncus. Ut convallis ante 
      at. 
     </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<script src="script.js"></script>
```

```
const list = document.querySelector('#book-list ul');

 list.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
if(e.target.className == 'delete') {
    const li = e.target.parentElement;

    li.parentNode.removeChild(li);
}
});

// add book-list

const addForm = document.forms['add-book'];

addForm.addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
e.preventDefault();

const value = addForm.querySelector('input[type="text"]').value;
console.log(value);
})
```

Comment: No one wants to look at a video to see code. What does the code look like.

Comment: The submit buttons triggers the submit event on the form. You listen for submit on the form. The only action the button has could be the click/mouse action. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/submit_event

Comment: Added the code sorry

Answer (score 0):

A submit button triggers the [submit event handler](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/submit_event) on a form. That is why you listen for the submit event on the form and not a button.